# In FIutter : have one screen for both login and sign up, and i failed to make the card flexible in height when i switch between them

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, provider, card

- This the main screen and on it i have the AuthCard widget that i use to switch between Login and Signup.

```
import 'package:Zabatnee/common_app/provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:Zabatnee/common_app/widgets/auth_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/signUpScreen';

  @override
  _SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
  var isVerified = true;
  var isInit = true;
  var _isLogin = true;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {

    if(isInit){
      isVerified = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).isVerified;
    }
    isInit = false;

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: deviceSize.height,
                width: deviceSize.width,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/Images/Login-bg.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(224, 254, 240, 1).withOpacity(.5),
              ),
              Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(35),
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 70),
                        // transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(-8 * pi / 180)
                        // ..translate(-10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(blurRadius: 8, offset: Offset(0, 2))
                            ]),
                        child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/Images/zabatnee_logo.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: _isLogin ? deviceSize.height*.35 :deviceSize.height*.6,              
                        child: AuthCard(isVerified),)
                  ],
                ),
              
            ],
          
        );
  }
}
```

- and below the widget which contain a boolean (_isLogin), what i need is when i choose login the height of card to be deviceSize.height*.35 and when i use Signup to be deviceSize.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: deviceSize.width * .85,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Card(
              
              color: Colors.black54,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              elevation: 8,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        if (!_isLogin)
                          TextFormField(
                            key: ValueKey('first name'),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                              FocusScope.of(context)
                                  .requestFocus(_lastNameFocusNode);
                            },
                            autofocus: false,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'please enter your first name';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            onSaved: (value) {
                              _signupModel.firstName = value;
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              focusColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              hintText: 'Please enter your First Name ...',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white24),
                              labelText: 'First Name',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          ),
                        if (!_isLogin)
                          TextFormField(
                            key: ValueKey('Last Name'),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              focusColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              hintText: 'Please enter your Last Name ...',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white24),
                              labelText: 'Last Name',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            focusNode: _lastNameFocusNode,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'please enter your last name';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                              FocusScope.of(context)
                                  .requestFocus(_emailFocusNode);
                            },
                            onSaved: (value) {
                              //_signupModel = SignUpModel(firstName: _signupModel.firstName, lastName: value,email: _signupModel.email, mobile: _signupModel.mobile, password: _signupModel.password, countryCode: _signupModel.countryCode, gender: _signupModel.gender,sms: _signupModel.sms);
                              _signupModel.lastName = value;
                            },
                          ),
                        TextFormField(
                          key: ValueKey('email'),
                          autofocus: false,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                            FocusScope.of(context)
                                .requestFocus(_phoneFocusScope);
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            _signupModel.email = value;
                          },
                          decoration: _isLogin
                              ? InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.person,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  hintText: 'Please enter your email...',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white24),
                                  labelText: 'Email',
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                )
                              : InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  hintText: 'Please enter your email...',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white24),
                                  labelText: 'Email',
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                              return 'please enter a valid email';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        ),
                        if (!_isLogin)
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                child: CountryCodePicker(
                                  onInit: (code) {
                                    _signupModel.countryCode = '+20';
                                  },
                                  onChanged: (code) {
                                    _signupModel.countryCode = code.toString();
                                  },
                                  initialSelection: 'EG',
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, left: 8),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  key: ValueKey('phone number'),
                                  autofocus: false,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    hintText:
                                        'Please enter your Phone Number...',
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white24),
                                    labelText: 'Phone Number',
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                  focusNode: _phoneFocusScope,
                                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                                    FocusScope.of(context)
                                        .requestFocus(_passwordFocusNode);
                                  },
                                  maxLength: 10,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.length != 10) {
                                      return 'please enter a valid phone number';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  onSaved: (value) {
                                    _signupModel.mobile = value;
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        TextFormField(
                          key: ValueKey('password'),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_) {},
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            _signupModel.password = value;
                          },
                          focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
                          obscureText: _showPassword ? false : true,
                          decoration: _isLogin
                              ? InputDecoration(
                                  suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      _togglevisibility();
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(_showPassword
                                        ? Icons.visibility
                                        : Icons.visibility_off),
                                  ),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.lock,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: 'Please enter your password...',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white24),
                                  labelText: 'Password',
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                )
                              : InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: 'Please enter your password...',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white24),
                                  labelText: 'Password',
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.length < 6) {
                              return 'please enter password lager that 6 character';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        if (!_isLogin)
                          Container(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Date Of Birth',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.date_range,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          _selectDateOfBirth(context);
                                          _removeFocus();
                                        }),
                                    FlatButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        _selectDateOfBirth(context);
                                        _removeFocus();
                                      },
                                      child: Text(
                                        formatted == null
                                            ? 'No Date Choosen!'
                                            : formatted,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        if (!_isLogin)
                          Container(
                            child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    'Gender',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  RadioListTile(
                                    value: 'Male',
                                    activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
                                    onChanged: (val) {
                                      setSelectedRadioTile(val);
                                      print(val);
                                    },
                                    title: Text(
                                      'Male',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  RadioListTile(
                                    value: 'Female',
                                    activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
                                    onChanged: (val) {
                                      setSelectedRadioTile(val);
                                      print(val);
                                    },
                                    title: Text(
                                      'Female',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                          ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (_isLoading)
            CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          if (!_isLoading)
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                _isLogin ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              onPressed: saveForm,
            ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              '${_isLogin ? 'SIGN UP' : 'LOGIN'} INSTEAD',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _switchAuthMode();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the method which i use to switch between login and signup:

```
 void _switchAuthMode() {
    if (_isLogin) {
      setState(() {
        _isLogin = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLogin = true;
      });
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap those cardviews with animated container and change their heights using setstate and boolean.

That will result in the UI you are working to obtain, I presume.

Let me know if it helps, or you need more help.

Comment: this is what you mean by use setState :void _switchAuthMode() {
    if (_isLogin) {
      setState(() {
        _isLogin = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLogin = true;
      });
    }

  }
 as i do it and use a boolean in height of the animatedContainer but i does not change the height of card